# Echo prints only first character of string after update to php7

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string, echo

I'm working on a wordpress site in which I want post titles to appear on the front page. As I'm rather inexperienced, I mimicked the code that was already there (showing category titles). I basically created an array of titles, called $title, which parses get_the_title of the corresponding post. I wouldn't say I completely understand the entire structure, but it worked at first.

However, I just updated to PHP 7 and in stead of printing the full title, it prints only the first character of the post title. 
Maybe I'm using the arrays in a wrong way, or the 'get_the_title'-function changed, but I cannot seem to get it to work like it used to. Any hints would be highly appreciated!

The basic structure is like below. However, the entire code is much bigger, it being part of an already existing WP-feature.

```
$count  =   0;
while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :
$cat_query->the_post();
global $post;

$thumb[$count]  =   get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

$title[$count] = get_the_title( $post->title);

$count++;


<div class="category-thumb-1 grid-item">
   <?php if ( isset($thumb[0]) && ($thumb[0] != '') ) : echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb[0], 'large');
   <div class="post-title-1">
   <a href="<?php echo $link[0]?>" <span><?php echo $title[0]?></span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could happen with `$title[0]` if `$title` was a string instead of an array.  To check this, try using `$title` and see what it displays.

Comment: If you do a var_dump what does it show for `$title`?

Comment: $title contains all the first characters of the titles in the array

Comment: Struggling to read this but I would say that you need to have
$title = get_the_title($post->title);
then <?php echo $title; ?>
or just $title = $post->title;

You just need to do some var_dumps or echos for $post->title, $post and $title.
Work out what you have and what you need to echo

Comment: To be completely honest, I wouldn't know how to do a var_dump, but I'll try to move some things around after your suggestions, thanks :)

Comment: When in doubt about how something works check out `php.net` they have everything documented https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php. In short `var_dump($title)`

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where to look for the output of var_dump if I don't print it somewhere directly in my html document. That probably sounds stupid, but I've recently started by just copying and altering the files of my wordpress installation (in a child theme), and seeing the changes in the browser. Which was probably not the proper thing to do.... :}

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks everyone for your suggestions. In the end, I managed to get the var_dump going (which is going to help me a lot in the future), and found the solution.

var_dump was giving me not an array, but a string of the three first character of the titles (so if my titles would be 'Apple' 'Pear' 'Banana', my $title would be set to 'APB', in stead of an array of 0-> Apple, 1->Pear, 2-> Banana. Strangely, the $link-array *did* work exactly as I wished.

I ended up switching the names around and got $link working wite get_the_title. Then I decided to rename $title to $titl and this did the trick. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you have described would indicate you initialized `$title` as a string, not an array, the `[]` then accesses the nth character of that string and populates it with the one character.

Examples of this behavior can be seen with:

```
$test = '';
for($count = 0; $count < 5; $count++) {
    $test[$count] = $count;
}
```

with

```
$test = array();
for($count = 0; $count < 5; $count++) {
    $test[$count] = $count;
}
```

The `$count` actually also isn't need nor the initialization. You can just use `[]` and the index will auto increment.

```
while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :
    $cat_query->the_post();
    global $post;
    $thumb_unique[] = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $title_unique[] = get_the_title( $post->title);
<div class="category-thumb-1 grid-item">
   <?php if ( isset($thumb_unique[0]) && ($thumb_unique[0] != '') ) : echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb_unique[0], 'large');
   <div class="post-title-1">
   <a href="<?php echo $link[0]?>" <span><?php echo $title_unique[0]?></span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

syntax here seems a bit off but modified it just as an example.